# Custom directive scope element visible but undefined

Tags: angularjs, scope, angular-directive

I made a custom directive that retrieves data from a controller.

My variable is visible inside the scope element but when trying to access it, I got *undefined*

**HTML**

```
<map borders="vm.borders"></map>
```

**Directive**

```
angular.module('myApp.directives')
.directive('map', [ function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            borders: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope); //cfr linked image
            console.log(scope.borders) //undefined
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the scope. It contains the borders variable.

[image: scope console]

What am I missing to retrieve this borders value ?

Comment: are you assigning values to `vm.borders`?  I dont see any issues [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cg8e3emv/)

Comment: When you console.log an object the properties aren't evaluated until you hit the arrow in the console to expand the object.  the property logging shows the value is undefined at runtime when it hits the log statement.  Ng if will avoid the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could suggest to add an `ng-if` to the directive, because for example if `vm.borders` are got from a promise, `ng-if` is required:

```
<map borders="vm.borders" ng-if="vm.borders"></map>
```

Comment: Simple and clear, it works. Accepting as answer in 6minutes

Comment: Yep, ng-if often helps. Thanks.